# SMTP authentification: saslauthd won't start

Tags: sasl, saslauthd

I've set up a mailserver, which is working fine, but now I wanted to add SMTP authentification using SASL. However, trying to start saslauthd (my system is Ubuntu 16.04) doesn't work, but I don't get any error message as well.
This is the my /etc/default/saslauthd, which should be correct for my server (smptd is not running as chroot):
[/etc/default/saslauthd](http://pastebin.com/euxKvzHp)

I got saslauthd it running at one point (five instances were shown by ps), but when I tested it using telnet it seemed that its interaction with postfix is still not working, so I tried to change a huge number of things, but no matter what I did to revert those changes, I couldn't make saslauthd start again.

This is the strace output when trying to start saslauthd:
[strace output](http://pastebin.com/nntLngVm)

I can't find any relevant information about why it doesn't start in this output though.

Does someone have an idea what the cause for this could be? Or what I could do in order to find it out?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: I don't know if this might be of any help, but this is the script in /etc/init.d/ for starting saslauthd: http://pastebin.com/MjSyxLWG I don't get any error message at all when trying to start the service, it just won't create the five instances it should create.

Comment: Calling /etc/init.d/saslauthd restart doesn't work (though reporting "ok"), but directly calling "saslauthd -a sasldb -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5" works. Therefore I can only imagine that saslauthd doesn't possess enough rights when being evoked by the init.d script, but still that's quite strange since this is how it should be done normally.

Comment: Evoking saslauthd manually didn't work as well, since it won't interact with postfix then. I think it's really odd that calling "/etc/init.d/saslauthd reload" reports "ok", but doesn't create any instance of an saslauthd process. Here' the strace output of "/etc/init.d/saslauthd reload": http://pastebin.com/MJx6HNwt Maybe someone could take a look at this while comparing it with the /etc/init.d/saslauthd script itself which I also pasted (s. original post)?